# MySQL Comparing field using concat with two fields

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have the following MySQL Query:

```
SELECT concat_ws('/', exp_month, exp_year) as exp_date 
FROM `cc_info`
WHERE concat_ws('/', exp_month, exp_year) <= '05/12'
```

The query is pulling back results in the future as well as in the past. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings in lexicographical order, and the month comes before the year. If you put the year before the month, then they will be in the correct order:

```
SELECT concat_ws('/', exp_year, exp_month) as exp_date 
FROM `cc_info`
WHERE concat_ws('/', exp_year, exp_month) <= '12/05'
```

Comment: Thanks! I should pay more attention to my syntax lol. I ended up having to do a few things different (writing a Ruby script) because of a legacy DB. The DB has 3 different expiration_{type} columns. Legacy uses exp_month and exp_year while the new system uses expiration_date. Exp_year and Exp_month are `varchar`while expiration_date is `datetime`. So I had to do some conversion of the characters to get it all working properly